# Add sound to push notifications

Tags: ios, django, apple-push-notifications, django-push-notifications

I'm using [django-push-notifications](https://github.com/jazzband/django-push-notifications) to send push to our ios users (using APNS).

```
from push_notifications.models import APNSDevice, APNSDeviceQuerySet

from apps.notifications.db.models import Notification
from apps.users.db.models import User


class APNSService:
    def __init__(self, user: User, title: str, body: str, data: dict):
        self.user = user
        self.title = title
        self.body = body
        self.data = data

    def get_devices(self) -> APNSDeviceQuerySet:
        return APNSDevice.objects.filter(user=self.user)

    def send_message(self):
        return self.get_devices().send_message(
            message=dict(
                title=self.title,
                body=self.body
            ),
            badge=Notification.objects.filter(recipient=self.user, unread=True).count(),
            extra=self.data
        )
```

The problem is, that notifications comes without a sound. According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW1), there should be extra field to execute the sound when notification is received.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is param `sound`, example

```
def send_message(self):
    return self.get_devices().send_message(
        message=dict(
            title=self.title,
            body=self.body
        ),
        extra=self.data,
        sound="default",
    )
```